# How to set a column to today's date in SQL Server when user modifies another column in table in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access

My setup is as such. I have an MS Access front end which points to a linked table in SQL Server. Via the form, the user updates one of the fields in the linked table throughout the day. My query is how do I update another column with today's date whenever a user changes it manually in the MS Access front end?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Use triggers. Or you can write query which takes current date also along with the other column data.

Comment: But the user does not run an update query. They literally type in stuff into the column in MS Access front end. And it autosaves into the table. WIll a trigger work in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice discusion of this problem here:  [Best way to implement a last-modified column in Sql Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341602/best-way-to-implement-a-last-modified-column-in-sql-server-2005)

The accepted answer that time around was to use a [TRIGGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx).

There are lots of good reasons to avoid triggers (see http://devproconnections.com/sql-server/reasons-avoid-triggers).  But auditing can be hard to achieve by other methods.